# 500 Internal Server Error when browsing to domain, works when browsing to index.html

Tags: apache, web-hosting

So basically when browsing to http://www.tracegenie.co.za there is an internal 500 Error message, but when browsing to http://www.tracegenie.co.za/index.html it works.

Permissions all look fine (plus permissions would not be the issue if the latter works, right?).

I have checked the Apache DirectoryIndex Priority via WHM (index.html is right at the top of the list). I have added a .htaccess file to the public_html folder (where index.html is located) with `DirectoryIndex index.html`. (Also checked the permissions on the .htaccess file).

I am at my wit's, end and I have no further solutions to try. Please help?

[image: public_html directory contents]

Comment: Can you share the .htaccess, my guess is that there is a rewrite loop. Also, with error 500, there must be something in the logs, check there

Comment: The .htaccess is simply `DirectoryIndex index.html`. That is the only line in the file. Without the .htacess file I get the same error. I cannot find anything in the logs, the last entry in the error logs was 09 August 2016.

Comment: @DusanBajic I found the correct apache log file (finally) and the error is:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

I found a bunch of solutions all to do with .htaccess rewrite issues, but my .htaccess does not have any rewrite functionality and the issue persists even without a .htaccess file.

Comment: Then you have redirect in your apache .conf file?